# In which folder does TIDAL store its music files?

Tags: music, tidal

I've TIDAL installed and would like to find the music files to check how big they are at HiFi and Master quality. Where are they located?

I've searched on Google and can't find anything and also I've browsed my PC several times unlucky.

Comment: If you can believe reddit then "It doesnt store music files. It stores a song in like a million of teeny tiny little files only readable by Tidal."

Comment: Ah, yeah. Just remembered that TIDAL doesn't have offline listening on PC's... Having a look in my Androids file system I can confirm millions of small files in the cache, and in the offline folder files ranging between 90 and 20 MB with random names and no extension.